# Spring webflux unit test method which returns Mono/Flux

Tags: unit-testing, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using spring webflux in my project. My controller class calls service class methods which returns Mono or Flux.

I am trying to write unit tests for my service class. I am not sure how to write unit tests for a method which returns Mono/Flux. Most of the articles I checked suggested me to use WebclientTest. But the point is, I am testing my service class here. I have used WebclientTest when I tested my web layer(controller class) by mocking service class methods.

Now I want to write unit tests for my service class methods(by mocking database class)

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Should I use call the service class method from test and call `block()` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StepVerifier` provided by Project Reactor for [testing](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing) purposes.

Although, for simple scenarios (for example when you only have a `Mono`) a `block` call will do just fine.

`StepVerifier` might come in handy when you...

- have a `Flux` and want to assert multiple items/events flowing through the pipeline
- deal with time
- test Reactor context

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was wondering if spring provides any abstraction on top of project reactor..